# Operator Overloading to show error on invalid input

Tags: c++, matrix, error-handling, operator-overloading

I am overloading the addition and subtraction operator for a matrix class I'm writing. Is there a way for me to show an error if someone tries to add two matrices of different dimensions, like if you try `int a = a + b;` where b is of other type than int, it will give me error directly, is there a way to do this to my class? If not, what is a possible way to handle this?

Comment: Of course there is. Are they template parameters? Members? An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would go a long way.

Comment: For now, I'm doing an int matrix class, but after I'm done with it, I'll change it to a template class

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a template, NO!
Compile time error will be identified by compiler for what it can detect at compile time, so if dimensions of matrix will be identified at runtime, compiler can't know anything about it and you must identify error with an exception or something like that. But if dimensions of matrix will be identified by template arguments compiler can know them and generate errors at compile time, but using this approach you can't get dimension from the user at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of your matrix is set at compile time through, for example, non-type template parameters, then the striaghtforward template implementation of the oeprator would automatically detect and error on such mismatches.

If however the size of your matrix is set at runtime through the constructor or other means, it's probably not possible to detect at compile time (unless there is a lot of `constexpr` involved in the entire sizing call chain). The best you can do in this case is a runtime assertion that the sizes match.